# Jenkins Declarative jekinsFile syntax

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to write a jenkins file that will allow me to have a non-blocking input step (i.e. an input step that will use a flyweight executor rather than a heavyweight one). Whilst I have managed to do this in a test project, I'm having issues incorporating an environment section in my file for my real project. My jenkins file currently looks like this...

```
pipeline {
agent none
stages {
    stage('Env Set Up'){
        agent {label 'cm-linux-15916'}
        environment {
            def JAVA_HOME = tool('1.8.0.65_Linux')
            def MAVEN_EXEC = tool('3.3.3_Linux')
            PATH="${JAVA_HOME}/jre/bin:${MAVEN_EXEC}/bin:/build/build_tools/nodejs/6.7.0/bin/:$PATH"
        }
    }
    stage('DEV Build & Sonar') {
        agent {label 'cm-linux-15916'}
        steps {
            echo 'DEV BUILD STARTED HERE...'
            sh("/build_tools/maven/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin/mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=${Major}.${Minor}.${Point}.${BUILD_NUMBER}-SNAPSHOT -X")
            sh("/build_tools/maven/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin/mvn clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.4.201502262128:prepare-agent deploy sonar:sonar")        
        }
    }
    stage('DEV Deploy') {
        agent {label 'cm-linux-15916'}
        steps {
            withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: '2b714cb5-d136-4555-97bc-f33ba1695a02',
            usernameVariable: 'uname',
            passwordVariable: 'passwd')])
            {
                sh('chmod 755 ansible_dev.sh')
                sh('./ansible_dev.sh')
                sh('chmod 644 ansible_dev.sh')
            }
        }
    }
    stage('SIT Build & Deploy?') {
        agent none
        steps {
            timeout(time:24, unit:'HOURS') {
                input('Do you want to proceed with SIT deployments?')
            }
        }
    }
```

This give me

```
WorkflowScript: 4: Nothing to execute within stage "Env Set Up" @ line 4, column 5.
   stage('Env Set Up'){
```

I've also tried the approach below...

```
pipeline {
agent none

environment {
    def JAVA_HOME = tool('1.8.0.65_Linux')
    def MAVEN_EXEC = tool('3.3.3_Linux')
    PATH="${JAVA_HOME}/jre/bin:${MAVEN_EXEC}/bin:/build/build_tools/nodejs/6.7.0/bin/:$PATH"
}

stages {

    stage('DEV Build & Sonar') {
        agent {label 'cm-linux-15916'}
        steps {
            echo 'DEV BUILD STARTED HERE...'
            sh("/build_tools/maven/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin/mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=${Major}.${Minor}.${Point}.${BUILD_NUMBER}-SNAPSHOT -X")
            sh("/build_tools/maven/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin/mvn clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.4.201502262128:prepare-agent deploy sonar:sonar")        
        }
    }
    stage('DEV Deploy') {
        agent {label 'cm-linux-15916'}
        steps {
            withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: '2b714cb5-d136-4555-97bc-f33ba1695a02',
            usernameVariable: 'uname',
            passwordVariable: 'passwd')])
            {
                sh('chmod 755 ansible_dev.sh')
                sh('./ansible_dev.sh')
                sh('chmod 644 ansible_dev.sh')
            }
        }
    }
    stage('SIT Build & Deploy?') {
        agent none
        steps {
            timeout(time:24, unit:'HOURS') {
                input('Do you want to proceed with SIT deployments?')
            }
        }
    }
```

this give me

```
Required context class hudson.model.Node is missing
Perhaps you forgot to surround the code with a step that provides this, such as: node
```

I'm really struggling to get the syntax correct on this, without the environment section I can get everything to work as expected. Can anyone assist me?

**UPDATE**

My latest attempt is to include the env variables in a script section within the first stage as below

```
pipeline {
agent none
stages {
    stage('DEV Build & Sonar') {
        agent {label 'cm-linux-15916'}
        steps {
            script{
                def JAVA_HOME = tool('1.8.0.65_Linux')
                def MAVEN_EXEC = tool('3.3.3_Linux')
                //PATH="${JAVA_HOME}/jre/bin:${MAVEN_EXEC}/bin:/build/build_tools/nodejs/6.7.0/bin/:$PATH"
                PATH="/build/build_tools/jdk/1.8.0.65/jre/bin:/build/build_tools/nodejs/6.7.0/bin/:$PATH"
                JAVA_HOME="/build/build_tools/jdk/1.8.0.65/jre/"
                echo 'DEV BUILD STARTED HERE...'
                sh("/build_tools/maven/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin/mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=${Major}.${Minor}.${Point}.${BUILD_NUMBER}-SNAPSHOT -X")
                sh("/build_tools/maven/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin/mvn clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.4.201502262128:prepare-agent deploy sonar:sonar")        
            }
        }
    }
        stage('DEV Deploy') {
            agent {label 'cm-linux-15916'}
            steps {
                withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: '2b714cb5-d136-4555-97bc-f33ba1695a02',
                usernameVariable: 'uname',
                passwordVariable: 'passwd')])
                {
                    sh('chmod 755 ansible_dev.sh')
                    sh('./ansible_dev.sh')
                    sh('chmod 644 ansible_dev.sh')
                }
            }
        }
        stage('SIT Build & Deploy?') {
            agent none
            steps {
                timeout(time:24, unit:'HOURS') {
                    input('Do you want to proceed with SIT deployments?')
                }
            }
        }
```

This feels closer to what I want although I'm now getting an error...

```
 Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project orc-admin-service-wlp: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 1.8 -> [Help 1]
```

this seems to be coming from the mvn clean step

Comment: What's the difference between you test project and this?

Comment: The difference is that my test project doesn't require an environment section. so it seems that the environment section requires an agent. But if I declare an agent directly under the pipeline syntax, then I'm back to square one in that I'm holding an executor for the life of the build....I've added an update to the question with my latest attempt!